# How do I use xgettext to scan JS file

Tags: javascript, gettext, xgettext

How do I use `xgettext` by invoking the `xgettext` program in Window 10?

I tried the following, and it didn't work.

```
xgettext --language=JavaScript --from-code=utf-8 --keyword=gettext --sort-output --join-existing --no-wrap -f videobanner.js -d snapmaker -o output.po
```

The `videobanner.js` file:

```
export default {
    bannerH1Text: gettext("Snapmaker 3-in-1 3D Printer"),
    bannerH1Text: gettext("Turn your desktop into a workshop."),
    bannerButText: ettext("Play Video"),
};
```

Command gives the error:

> xgettext: error while opening "export default {" for reading: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> -f, --files-from=FILE
>     get list of input files from FILE

If you use `-f`, that file is supposed to contain a list of file names that xgettext should work on. Instead of that, just pass your file as a plain argument:

```
xgettext ... videobanners.js
```

No `-f`!